# Is it possible to use Twisted with IPv6?

Tags: python, twisted, ipv6

I'm trying to add IPv6 support to an application written with Twisted, which unfortunately does not support IPv6.  There's a three-year-old [ticket](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3014) for this in Twisted's trac, but it seems to be stuck in debate with no indication of progress any time soon.

Ideally I'd like existing reactor methods like listenTCP and connectTCP to simply work, i.e. connectTCP would accept either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses and deal with the socket differences behind the scenes.  The ticket does include a patch to do this, but it's rather old, and completely untested, so not really suitable for a production app, except as a reference point.

Before I spend a lot of time writing my own patch, I'm wondering whether anyone else has dealt with this, and if so, how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Use `HostnameEndpoint` to connect to a remote host regardless of its address family.

Comment: This answer is quite out-of-date, now, right?  The ticket referenced in closed, and searching ipv6 in the twisted issue tracker turns up tickets that appear to show that it is fixed for TCP, but not yet UDP.  Is this correct?

Comment: You can send UDP6 traffic just fine, but since there’s no standard happy-eyeballs-like standard for UDP, you need to decide how you’re going to interact with name resolution on your own.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer to conform to the present realoty more closely.

Comment: You rock, obviously.